# How To Find The Parent Of A Node That Has The Value Of X

Tags: java

I am trying to write a function called `findParent(Int x)` that finds the value of the parent node of the node that has the value x in a Binary Search Tree.

```java
main

BSTTest mytree = new BSTTest();

mytree.add(25);
mytree.add(55);
mytree.add(15);
mytree.add(12);
mytree.add(54);
mytree.add(13);
mytree.add(56);
mytree.add(60);
mytree.add(57);
mytree.add(53);

System.out.println("Root: " + mytree.getRoot());
System.out.println("Level: " + mytree.findLevel(13));
System.out.println("Parent: " + mytree.findParent(53));
```

```
private class Node{
    private int key;
    private Node left;
    private Node right;
    private Node parent;

    public Node(int x) {// Node constructor
        key = x;
        left = null;
        right =null;
        parent = null;
    }
}
```

```
public int findParent(int x) {
    return findParent(root,x);
}

private int findParent(Node N, int x) {
    Node nextNode = null;

    if(x < N.key && N.left != null) {
        nextNode = N.left;
        nextNode.parent = N;
        return findParent(nextNode,x);
    }
    else if(x > N.key && N.right != null) {
        nextNode = N.right;
        nextNode.parent = N;
        return findParent(nextNode, x);
    }
    else if(x < N.key && N.left == null) {
        return N.key;
    }
    else if(x > N.key && N.right ==null) {
        return N.key;
    }
    else {
        return N.parent.key;
    }
}
```

For some reason when I run this code I am able to get the parent value of a node in the left side of the tree but I cant on the right side.
For example when i find the parent value of 13 i get 12 which is correct, but when I look for the parent value of 53 i get 55 instead of 54.

[image]

Comment: Could You also paste the `Node` code ?

Comment: And Possibly also the `BSTTest`.

Comment: Yes. I just added it right now.

Comment: I'd suggest to remove the use of parent, as it is may be unwanted side affect to set a field inside function meant to search a node

Answer (score 0):

The method should be read-only. Modifying the parent links inside it is kind of surprising. And code surprises are not a good thing.

If we assume that your other tree-modifying methods are maintaining the `parent` links correctly (your problem probably was that `findParent` sometimes did not do that) and make the method read-only, then:

```
public int findParent(int x) {
        return findParent(root,x);
    }
    private int findParent(Node N, int x) {
        if(x < N.key && N.left != null) {
            return findParent(N.left, x);
        }
        else if(x > N.key && N.right != null) {
            return findParent(N.right, x);
        }
        else if(x != N.key) {
            return N.key;
        }
        else {
            return N.parent.key;
        }
    }
```

Not that it actually needs the parent links to work:

```
public int findParent(int x) {
        return findParent(root,x,null);
    }
    private int findParent(Node N, int x, Node parent) {
        if (N == null || N.key == x) {
            if (parent != null) {
                return parent.key;
            } else {
                return ???; // you were asked for parent of root, no idea what result you want here
            }
        }
        if(x < N.key) {
            return findParent(N.left, x, N);
        } else {
            return findParent(N.right, x, N);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Could this be adapted to find the value of a right child or left child of a node with the value of x?

Comment: @Eric it's a few lines, I would not think of it as adapting; it's possible to write a function like that, sure, go for it